# Can't open a PDF file using pdfplumber.open

Tags: python

I've been following a YouTube channel called "Pythonic accountant", and I've been attempting to replicate tutorial 4, which teaches how to extract data from a PDF invoice, but I'm failing. I keep getting an error that I can't figure out how to resolve yet. I'm using anaconda and Jupyter notebooks on OSx. My code looks like this:

```
    import requests
    import pdfplumber

    def download_file(url):
        local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]

        with requests.get(url) as r:
            with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
        
        return local_filename

    invoice_url = 'http://www.k-billing.com/example_invoices/professionalblue_example.pdf'

    invoice = download_file(invoice_url)

    with pdfplumber.open(invoice) as pdf:
        page = pdf.pages[0]
        text = page.extract_text()
```

In the tutorial, the code runs fine. In my case, I get the following error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-6-de1887236e07> in <module>
    ----> 1 with pdfplumber.open(invoice) as pdf:
          2     page = pdf.pages[0]
          3     text = page.extract_text()

    AttributeError: module 'pdfplumber' has no attribute 'open'
```

I've installed the `pdfplumber` using `pip install`. I've searched for this error on the web. I can't figure out what I've done wrong.

Comment: Can you confirm the version of `pdfplumber` you have installed?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Please be really careful when editing questions. Unlikely, but what if that missing empty line you added actually caused a problem? I have seen weird things with python ... so, as said ... be careful what you change.

Comment: @GhostCat I am fully aware of that. This is why for example I didn't touch the Syntax Error under the second `with` statement. I believe adding a blank line shouldn't change anything and just makes the code a bit more readable for other people trying to help.

Comment: Hello @Tomerikoo. Looking at anaonda, it says i have version 0.1.2 of PDFPlumber installed.

Answer (score 0):

The indent here is wrong:

```
        with requests.get(url) as r:
            with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
```

it should be:

```
        with requests.get(url) as r:
            with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(r.content)
```

It works for me after the correction on `Ubuntu 20.04` with `Python 3.8.2` and `requests==2.22.0`.

---

I am not using OSX and **the code does work for me**. Therefore here is how I installed `pdfplumber` there could be something about versions you use what can point you to right direction.

```
✓ alirvah ~ $ pip3 install pdfplumber
Collecting pdfplumber
  Downloading pdfplumber-0.5.24.tar.gz (42 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 42 kB 630 kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow>=7.0.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pdfplumber) (7.0.0)
Collecting Wand
  Downloading Wand-0.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 133 kB 1.7 MB/s 
Collecting pdfminer.six==20200517
  Downloading pdfminer.six-20200517-py3-none-any.whl (5.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.6 MB 2.1 MB/s 
Collecting sortedcontainers
  Downloading sortedcontainers-2.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting pycryptodome
  Downloading pycryptodome-3.9.9-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (13.7 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 13.7 MB 3.8 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: chardet; python_version > "3.0" in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pdfminer.six==20200517->pdfplumber) (3.0.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: pdfplumber
  Building wheel for pdfplumber (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for pdfplumber: filename=pdfplumber-0.5.24-py3-none-any.whl size=31123 sha256=e8edc98ee33fbe2caf6161ba8b9081a0dd798c8c747d8ceedff4f248cadf8e07
  Stored in directory: /home/alirvah/.cache/pip/wheels/2b/02/eb/8e0c88d08e0675b767895d4bcf54c0d4da1b37579b00409e0e
Successfully built pdfplumber
Installing collected packages: Wand, sortedcontainers, pycryptodome, pdfminer.six, pdfplumber
Successfully installed Wand-0.6.3 pdfminer.six-20200517 pdfplumber-0.5.24 pycryptodome-3.9.9 sortedcontainers-2.3.0
```

Result of the script:

```
INVOICE
Invoice No. I1083
Account # C1006
Date 08-14-2008
Due By 08-31-2008
Demo Company
Phone : 111-222-3333 Terms None
1234 Main Street E-Mail : 333-444-4444 PO No. PO1234
Ashland, KY 41102 Web : http://www.ksoftware.net Sales Rep SalesPerson1
Bill To Ship To
Test Customer Test Customer
1234 Main Street 1234 Main Street
Ashland, KY 41101 Ashland,  41101
CCooddee DDeessccrriippttiioonn QTY Price Line Total
SKU1222 Test Import Name - Description Goes Here 1 $10.00 $10.00
Labor - Example labor item. Quantity is number of hours spent,  1.5 $100.00 $150.00
price is hourly rate. Quantity accepts decimal values.
Notes
An invoice note can go here. Multi-line and even multi-page notes are supported.
PPaayymmeenntt  DDeettaaiillss
Subtotal $160.00
Shipping$10.00 Tax $0.78
UPS Ground Total $170.78
Payments (-) $0.00
Balance Due $170.78
An invoice footer can go here
```

Comment: That is surely not the problem and is probably a typo. OP is getting the error at a line ***after that***, so obviously it would be the error they would get...

Comment: Therefore I am providing output of `pip3 install pdfplumber` to have a reference what library version I am using.

Comment: Hello @Patrik, thank you for your input. I must apologise, the indentation is a typo when i transposed the code from Jupyter to stack overflow. My sincere apologies. I do notice though that it appears you have a different version of PDFplumber installed. I have 0.1.2 and it appears yours is 0.5.24 installed. Perhaps thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a problem with my attempts to install of the PDFplumber package. For some reason, i was installing an older version (0.1.2). Once i resolved that, and had the correct package installed (0.5.24), the script ran fine and i was able to complete the tutorial. Thank you for your contribution & help